# How can I get my rotating platform script working in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a 2D game as a beginner. I want to add a platform, which is rotating around a center. I already have all things in the script, but hiding the center of the platform and the clockwise rotation is not working at all, so I wanted to ask if someone could improve my script. I also wanted to make it like it is in the Advanced Platforms 2D asset in the unity asset store, like on the screenshot. So you can choose your platform and the center.

Thanks!

Screenshot: [Advanced Platforms 2D Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZgTu.png)

Current Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotating_Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Transform rotationCenter;
    public GameObject rotationObject;

    [SerializeField]
    float rotationRadius = 2f, angularSpeed = 2f;
    float posX, posY, angle = 0f;
    private float rotZ;
    public bool ClockwiseRotation;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Rotation
        posX = rotationCenter.position.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * rotationRadius;
        posY = rotationCenter.position.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * rotationRadius;
        transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);
        angle = angle + Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;

        if (angle >= 360f)
            angle = 0f;

        //Clockwise Rotation
        if (ClockwiseRotation == false)
        {
            rotZ += Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            rotZ += -Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;
        } 
    }

    public bool HideRotationCenter;
    private void Loading_Initial_Parameters()
    {  
      //Hiding Rotation Center
      if (HideRotationCenter)
      {
         if (rotationCenter.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() != null)
         {
             rotationCenter.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
         }

         else
         {
            Debug.LogWarning("Rotation Center (" + rotationCenter.name + ") does NOT HAVE a SpriteRenderer Component to hide");
         }
      }

         else
         {
            //---Sprite renderers or Mesh renderers keep visible
         }


    }
}
```

Comment: 3 Questions. 1.- if you set the platform position in the rotation with `transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);` then what is `rotZ` for?? 2.- By "the clockwise rotation is not working at all" what do you mean? is counterClockwise rotation working or the platform does not move? What is the outcome? any errors in the console? 3.- Have you attached the `Rotating_Platform ` script to the platform gameObject?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay 1. It could be, that it rotZ isn't important at all because I pasted the clockwise rotation and also hiding the center. 2. Yes, the clockwise rotation is working, the counterClockwise not. And no Errors in the Console 3. No, it's attached to an empty GameObject to make it more clearly arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why center object isn't getting hidden

The reason why your center object is not getting hidden is because `Loading_Initial_Parameters()` method doesn't get called anywhere. You can fix that by calling it in the `Start()` method.

### Why clockwise rotation doesn't work

The reason why your `ClockwiseRotation` setting doesn't function properly is because the `angle` value goes in the same direction regardless of it. You can fix that by adding an `if else` statement which in one case will subtract the values and in another case add them.

### Modified version of your code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotating_Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform rotationCenter;

    public GameObject rotationObject;

    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationRadius = 2f, angularSpeed = 2f;

    public bool ClockwiseRotation;
    public bool HideRotationCenter;

    private float posX, posY, angle = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        Loading_Initial_Parameters();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Rotation
        posX = rotationCenter.position.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * rotationRadius;
        posY = rotationCenter.position.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * rotationRadius;
        rotationObject.transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);

        float angularMovement = Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;

        if (ClockwiseRotation)
            angle -= angularMovement;
        else
            angle += angularMovement;

        if (angle >= 360f)
            angle = 0f;
    }

    private void Loading_Initial_Parameters()
    {
        if (rotationCenter.TryGetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(out var rotationCenterSpriteRenderer))
        {
            rotationCenterSpriteRenderer.enabled = !HideRotationCenter;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(
                $"Rotation Center ({rotationCenter.name}) does NOT HAVE " +
                $"a SpriteRenderer Component to hide/show");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but everything is hidden, even if I unchecked the box.

Comment: @JonathanXD12 If that's the case, then it's probably due to having the `GameObject` or the rendering component already disabled in the scene itself.

Comment: @JonathanXD12 Just in case, updated the answer. The script should now both enable/disable `SpriteRenderer` based on your boolean value. Make sure that the `GameObject` itself is enabled though. Otherwise, feel free to have a look at `gameObject.SetActive()` method as an alternative to `component.enabled`.

Comment: No, that's so weird, the SpriteRenderer is on every object enabled. But it could be that the script isn't working right because I attached it to an empty GameObject like on this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/mQOOKFE

Comment: Hmm. The script doesn't seem to use `rotationObject` anywhere. Instead it uses `transform` of the `GameObject` it's attached to. Updated the answer - replaced the following line: `transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);`.

Comment: Now, everything is working properly thank you so much!!!